# R calculate month end

Tags: r, date

I have a question about date end, I explain in the following.
Here is my example data:

```
DATE
2015-01-01
2015-02-05
2015-09-29
2016-02-07
2016-07-24
2016-12-16
```

I know if I want the total days in that month, the code is:

```
days_in_month(DATE)
```

However, what I want is as following:

```
DATE            DATE_Month_End
2015-01-01      2015-01-31
2015-02-05      2015-02-28
2015-09-29      2015-09-30
2016-02-07      2016-02-29
2016-07-24      2016-07-31
2016-12-16      2016-12-31
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do this with:

```
library(lubridate)

DATE$DATE_Month_End <- DATE$DATE
day(DATE$DATE_Month_End) <- days_in_month(DATE$DATE)
```

since `day() <-` lets you change the day while keeping the year and month.

Comment: your answer is awesome. Can this write in just one line?

Comment: This is an elegant solution to a problem I was having. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
library(lubridate)
data$DATE <- ymd(data$DATE)
data$DATE_Month_End <- paste(format(data$DATE, format="%y-%m"),"-", days_in_month(data$DATE), sep="") 


  DATE           DATE_Month_End
1 2015-01-01       15-01-31
2 2015-02-05       15-02-28
3 2015-09-29       15-09-30
4 2016-02-07       16-02-29
5 2016-07-24       16-07-31
6 2016-12-16       16-12-31
```

Comment: NO. I know this. But I want if `DATE` is `2015-01-01`, `DATE_Month_End` is `2015-01-31`

Comment: I just edited above

Comment: Oh, your answer is good. But is there another way to get the same result and not using `paste`?

Comment: you could use also ceiling_date(data$DATE, unit = "month") - days(1)