# How to find maximum possible date in a month in R?

Tags: r, date

We have a questionnaire with some "fuzzy" items regarding the self-report time of some events. I would like to create a minimum and maximum possible dates for those times. Usually year and month are given, but day is missing. As such the minimum day works for every month since there is always a 1, but the max throws an error. Aside from trial and error, is there an easy way to look up how many days were in a month for a given year?

```
year <- c(2016, 2017)
month <- c(2, 2)
day <- c(29, 29)

as.Date(paste(year, month, day, sep='-'))
```

gives

```
> as.Date(paste(year, month, day, sep='-'))
[1] "2016-02-29" NA
```

but I want:

```
myDate(paste(year, month, day, sep='-'))
[1] "2016-02-29" "2016-02-28"
```

Comment: Look at lubiridate's `days_in_month` function. This post shows a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43772996/r-calculate-month-end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can subtract 1 day from the first of the following month

```
year.dat <- c(2016, 2017)
month.dat <- c(2, 2)
day.dat <- c(29, 29)

as.Date(paste (1, month.dat+1, year.dat, sep='-'), format = '%d-%m-%Y') - 1
#[1] "2016-02-29" "2017-02-28"
```

Note that this naiive version fails when the month is december, because as.Date then returns NA when we try to add one to the month.  To accomodate rolling december over to january of the next year we can improve this thusly:

```
as.Date(paste (1, c(1:12, 1)[month.dat+1], year.dat + (month.dat==12), sep='-'), format = '%d-%m-%Y') - 1
```

Comment: Arithmetic to the rescue yet again.

Comment: @AdamO -- note edit to this post to make sure it works also for December :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the "aggregate" function:

```
maxdaysbymonth <- aggregate(day ~ month, df, max)
mindaysbymonth <- aggregate(day ~ month, df, min)
```

Also you can extend that for years:

```
maxdaysbymonthbyyear <- aggregate(day ~ month + year, df, max)
mindaysbymonthbyyear <- aggregate(day ~ month + year, df, min)
```

Comment: For how many days consider the function "length" besides max or min at final.

Comment: Not the maximum observed date, the maximum possible date.